# Possible numbers with each digit value range given

Tags: combinations, permutation

We are given 3 variables, `d`, `a` and `b`.
`d` specifies the maximum number of places.
`a` and `b` specify the minimum digit and maximum digit respectively.
We have to find how many numbers can be made each of which has its digits in non-decreasing order, with maximum d places, and each digit between a and b, both inclusive.

```
Ex-
d = 1
a = 8
b = 9
Answer = 2 (Possible numbers are 8 and 9)


Ex-
d = 2
a = 8
b = 9
Answer = 5 (Possible numbers are 8, 9, 88, 89, and 99)
```

I have tried applying, permutation and combinations, but could not come across a generic answer for all values of d.

Also, I tried to observe patterns in possible numbers of each digit, but it seems to be varying.

What is the actual approach for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for combinations with repetition. All we have to do is generate all combinations with repetition of your set for each specific length up to `d`.

Below, we have a simple implementation in `C++`. First we need the appropriate `include` along with a function for return the number of combinations with repetition (i.e. `nChooseK`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

int nChooseK(int n, int k) {

    int nCk = 1;

    for (int i = (n - k + 1), d = 1; d <= k; ++i, ++d) {
        nCk *= i;
        nCk /= d;
    }

    return round(nCk);
}
```

And here is the algorithm for generating combinations with repetition:

```
void combsWithRep(std::vector<int> v, int d) {

    int numIter, maxZ, count = 0;
    int n = v.size();
    int d1 = d - 1, d2 = d - 2;
    std::vector<int> z(d, 0);
    int numRows = nChooseK(n + d - 1, d);

    maxZ = n - 1;

    while (count < numRows) {
        numIter = n - z[d1];;

        for (int i = 0; i < numIter; ++i, ++count, ++z[d1]) {
            for (int k = 0; k < d; ++k) {
                std::cout << v[z[k]];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        for (int i = d2; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (z[i] != maxZ) {
                ++z[i];
                for (int k = (i + 1); k < d; ++k)
                    z[k] = z[k - 1];

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `main` function:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int d, input;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of possible digits" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> d;

    std::cout << "\nEnter the digits" << std::endl;
    while (std::cin >> input)
        v.push_back(input);

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (int i = 1; i <= d; ++i)
        combsWithRep(v, i);

    return 0;
}
```

So, for an input of:

```
Enter the number of possible digits
4

Enter the digits
7
8
9
```

The output is:

```
7
8
9
77
78
79
88
89
99
777
778
779
788
789
799
888
889
899
999
7777
7778
7779
7788
7789
7799
7888
7889
7899
7999
8888
8889
8899
8999
9999
```

Comment: I think you interpreted the question wrong, we have to output only those numbers which have non-decreasing digits. So 898 is not allowed!

Comment: @Nisha Yes, I did interpret it wrong... I will delete it in a few minutes and work on a better solution. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks @JosephWood. I know it's too late and I might have overlooked the question back then. This indeed is a very nice and correct explanation. Thanks again